How to make hours optional in ISO_LOCAL_TIME formatter
I'm trying to make the hours 1 or two digits and optional by modifying the ISO_LOCAL_TIME formatter. This is for parsing durations where hours can be optional. This is what I tried.
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 1, 2, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .toFormatter()
        .withResolverStyle(STRICT);

//the duration is created like this
return Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, LocalTime.parse(formatted, formatter));

This is what I am testing with.
12:34:56.789
2:34:56.789
34:56.789
34:56 (mm:ss not hh:mm)

But it fails on the last two.
How can I create a formatter which passes all 4 tests?

I’m a bit late to the party. As has been said, neither use LocalTime nor DateTimeFormatter for a duration. The solution is to have regex convert your input string to the ISO 8601 format that Duration can parse. See it run online here. Other options include getting ThreeTen Extra or Time4J since they include support for parsing durations (and formatting them).

@Anonymous I figured it out! You can check my answer.

Your Question does not really make sense. (I mean that in a constructive way. Your Question is useful and educational.)
Ambiguity
How would you know that 12:34 is twelve minutes rather than 12 o’clock?
Time-of-day versus Span-of-Time
And, conceptually a number of minutes and seconds is not a time-of-day; it is a span of time.
Duration
Use Duration class to represent a span of time unattached to the timeline, on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.
ISO 8601
Rather than using the confusing ambiguous clock-format of HH:MM to represent a duration textually, use standard ISO 8601 format. Using the standard format may help to clarify your thinking and more clearly communicating your intentions. We need to  avoid conflating Time-of-day with Span-of-Time.
Example PT34M56S
The standard format starts with a PT. Then use H, M, and S to mark each hours-minutes-seconds portion. So thirty four minutes and fifty six minutes is PT34M56S.
This format is designed to be easily generated and parsed by both humans and machines. This format is relatively clear and intuitive even across human languages and cultural norms, needing only the briefest of explanation plus a few words in English or some Romance languages.
String input = "PT" + "34:56".replace( ":" , "M" ) + "S" ;
Duration duration = Duration.parse( input ) ;

Do some time math.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.NOON.plus ( duration ) ;


lt.toString() = 12:34:56


I agree with using the ISO format but this is not possible. These durations are from a specification (VAST Ads) and cannot be changed. The spec only says that milliseconds are optional but some devs do it wrong.

I added more info on how the duration is created.

@JohnMercier So, if two COLON characters are present, parse as a time of day. If only a single COLON is present, parse as a a duration (span of time).

Is there no way to do this with the formatter though? I did check online and it looks like joda time may have a period formatter that might work.

I ran into this issue again but figured it out this time so I am answering my own question.
The problem is using MINUTE_OF_HOUR requires the hour to be present, so any overflow has somewhere to go. This can be shown by creating a formatter for mm.ss. It needs to use MINUTE_OF_DAY instead and be LENIENT.
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .toFormatter()
        .withResolverStyle(LENIENT);

The solution is to make a formatter with two optional sections. One for MINUTES_OF_HOUR. The other for MINUTES_OF_DAY.
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 1, 2, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .toFormatter()
        .withResolverStyle(LENIENT);


(1) Thanks for answering your own question. (2) If you’re happy to force a duration o fit into a LocalTime, which it shouldn’t, OK with me. (3) It seems unnecessarily complicated to me, and I don’t understand why you would prefer it over a library that can directly parse a duration (like ThreeTen Extra or Time4J) or my solution using regex.

I can understand that. I'm just not sure how to do it with those other libraries. I checked the documentation and I'm not sure how.

Now I remember. I created a jmh test with a few different methods and the formatter is much faster than the other solutions.

I see. I just didn’t read in your question that you were under such tight time requirements that this little difference would matter.
